# How to print div excluding image with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div with a class of .coupon and inside is the coupon information along with an image. I need to find out how to print this without the image using jquery. Right now I have a some javascript that prints the entire thing and I do not want this.

Comment: I think CSS media queries will do that.  http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/

Comment: "Print" like *printer* or *screen*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your image a class and remove it using Jquery. For example:

HTML:

```
<div id="coupon">
<p>some text here</p>
<img class="hello" src="http://www.lumixgexperience.panasonic.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/gallery/AdamTrevor/Flower_HDR.jpg" />
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $( ".hello" ).remove();
});
```

The demonstration is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/sTeEH/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming HTML similar to this:

```
<div class="coupon">
    Some copy.
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
</div>
```

You can clone the object and remove the image:

```
$('.coupon').clone().find('img').remove();
```

Maybe move it offscreen to hide it and give it an ID for printing:

```
.offscreen {position: absolute; left: -999em;}

$('.coupon').clone().attr('id', 'myId').addClass('offscreen')
    .find('img').remove();
```